# pass param as xpath expressin to XSLT- javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt, xpath

Looking for a solution, on the following:
This is my javascript function which is setting a parameter to my xsl file and this parameter contains a string query which has a xpath syntx

```
queryFilter = "*/person[name='John']";

function getXSLDoc(xslDocument,xmlDocument,queryFilter) {
 ..
  var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
  processor.setParameter(null,"name",queryFilter);
....
}
```

Now on my xslt file I want to take queryFilter string and use it in a loop or create a variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:param name="queryFilter"/> 

<!-- Lets say I want to create a local variable and use it to loop on a node -->

    <xsl:variable name="varFilter" select="$queryFilter"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$**varFilter**">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
            ..
        </tr> 
    </xsl:for-each>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now how do I get to use the param i set on my javascript function as an xpath expression?

Comment: That XSLT file isn't valid. There are no templates. I'd suggest rewriting your XSLT.

Comment: Have you tried simply using the parameter *as is*, i.e. `<xsl:for-each select="$queryFilter">`?

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is dynamic evaluation of xpath, which is not supported in XSLT 1.0 (or 2.0), I think. You can use an extension function to do this though. Check out http://www.exslt.org/dyn/index.html for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support to evaluate a complete XPath expression dynamically at run-time. But for many cases it suffices to pass in a number or string value which you use in a comparison e.g.

```
name = "John";
```

and

```
processor.setParameter(null,"name",name);
```

and then in the XSLT you have

```
<xsl:param name="name"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="*/person[name = $name]">...</xsl:for-each>
```